# Proof that this graph has an exponential number of cliques

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, computational-mathematics, extremal-graph-theory

Below is a figure from [this paper](https://hal.inria.fr/file/index/docid/70393/filename/RR-5615.pdf), which analyzes the algorithmic problem of calculating maximal cliques of a graph.

Unfortunately, no citation or elaboration is given for this graph, other than the claim that is has an exponential number of cliques.

My question is: is the below graph a standard example in Graph Theory that has been used before (if so, where), and does there exist a reference for the proof that it has an exponential number of cliques?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular graph of course does not have an exponential number of cliques: it has $16$ maximal cliques (all with $4$ vertices, so they are also all maximum cliques). To talk about an exponential number of cliques, we need to generalize this example to a family of graphs.

The generalization suggested by the notation is the **cocktail party graph**: this has $2n$ vertices $u_1, u_2, \dots, u_n, v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n$, and all vertices are adjacent *except* for the pairs $\{u_i, v_i\}$ for $i=1,\dots,n$. (The terminology is meant to evoke $n$ couples that go to a party; each person shakes hands with everyone there other than their partner.)

In the cocktail party graph, $u_i$ and $v_i$ cannot simultaneously be in a clique. However, every clique that contains neither $u_i$ nor $v_i$ can be extended by adding either one of those vertices. So there are $2^n$ maximal cliques, all with $n$ vertices, obtained by choosing one vertex from each pair $\{u_i, v_i\}$.

This is a standard example of a graph with exponentially many cliques, and I don't think it needs a reference. But if you wanted to cite something, the Moon-Moser paper [On cliques in graphs](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02760024) proves that an $n$-vertex graph can have at most $3^{n/3}$ maximal cliques, and gives a related extremal example: take $n/3$ *triples* of vertices, and connect all vertices that are in different triples.